# Define searchable fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch-7

** using Elastichsearch version 7.3 **

We are defining template mapping for our index with all our fields types.

We don't want all our fields to be searchable.

Moreover, We would like that the default for each field will be **not** searchable and to have the option to define specific fields as searchable manually.

I am having trouble to understand the difference between ***store* / *enabeld* / *index*** attributes and can't decide which one of them will solve that issue and how to implement it.